# data class contructor in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

data class itemsInfo(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

```
@SerializedName("unit")
val unit: String,

@SerializedName("period")
val period: String,

@SerializedName("description")
val description: String,

@SerializedName("values")
val values: List<ChartValues>
```

) : Parcelable {

```
constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
    source.readString(),
    source.readString(),
    source.readString(),
    ArrayList<ChartValues>().apply {
        source.readList(
            this,
            ChartValues::class.java.classLoader
        )
    }

)
```

this is my data clas while making contructor unable to resolve "this" keyword. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one field in second constructor, that is why this can't be resolved.

```
constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
    source.readString(),
    source.readString(),
    source.readString(),
    source.readString(),
    ArrayList<ChartValues>().apply {
        source.readList(
            this,
            ChartValues::class.java.classLoader
        )
    }

)
```

Comment: Parcelable {
    constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
            source.readString(),
            source.readString(),
            source.readString(),
            source.readString(),
            ArrayList<ChartValue>().apply { source.readList(this, ChartValue::class.java.classLoader) }
    )

I tried that then getting error in readstring so i resolve like this